# webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null) gives an exception Class not registered

Tags: webview2, winforms-to-web

My Code structure is the following:

The project a class library called from an exe

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Browser : UserControl
    {
        public Browser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form_Resize);
            webView.NavigationStarting += EnsureHttps;
            InitializeAsync();
        }
        private async void InitializeAsync()
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
            webView.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += UpdateAddressBar;
        }
   }
}
```

Taken from the Winform example in github.

I am using WebView2 version: 1.0.955-prerelease targeting .NET Framework 4.8 and built using platform=x64

At the line: `webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null)`, I am getting the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type `'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'`
> occurred in mscorlib.dll Class not registered

The cache folder: `MyProject.dll.WebView2` is also not being created at the default location of the binaries.

Would be very grateful if someone could help out with this error.

Comment: The 'prerelease' version requires that you install Microsoft Edge CANARY build! Get it from here: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download

Comment: @PoulBak...thank you for the reply...I installed CANARY and it is still giving me the error. Also I have checked with the latest stable build too, and the error is the same. The thing is running this code from an exe is fine, when I put this code in a dll and the dll is called from an exe, is when the error occurs. Moreover the cache folder is not getting created...thnx

Comment: In the dll case where you see the failure, is the dll and the exe in the same folder? The webview2 .NET code tries to find the native webview2loader.dll which should be relative to the executable?

Comment: @DavidRisney, yes webview2loader.dll is relative to exe.

Comment: Oh, I forgot: Try setting the build to either 'x86' or 'x64', it can't always find the 'AnyCPU'.